# Why does Jason say that dope stuff or material stuff could go away?

Tags: dont-look-up

In the scene, Jason Orlean, the Chief of Staff of the United States,
addresses the world just before the launch of BEAD, a mission aiming
to bring back a comet to Earth and generate profits from it. During
his address, Jason expresses that he has noticed many people have been
praying during this time and commends them for it:

> Jason: There's dope stuff, like material stuff, like **sick apartments
> and watches, and cars, um, and clothes and shit that could all go
> away** and I don't  wanna see that stuff go away.

Why does Jason say that dope stuff or material stuff could go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'[Dope](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dope#:%7E:text=slang,a%20generalized%20term%20of%20approval)' and '[sick](https://www.dictionary.com/e/gnarly-nasty-sick-synonyms/)' are informal adjectives in modern American vernacular that mean

> "very good"

He is expressing that he finds all of the things listed below to be 'dope' (very good) and his hope that if the mission is successful, that they'll all still be available afterwards.

The alternative is that if the comet hits the planet, they'll all 'go away', which is another way of saying 'no longer be available'.